# Proof explanation: sequence in the probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Show that the sequence $(X_n/n)$ where $X_n ∼ χ_n^2$ converges to $1$ in probability.

I tried to solve it, but I dont know how to do it, any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_n \sim \chi^2(n)$, then $X_n = Z_1^2 + \cdots + Z_n^2$ Where the $Z_i$ are independent random variables with normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Using this information, the rest of the proof is just an application of the *law of large numbers*: in fact $(Z_i^2)$ is a sequence of independent random variables with mean
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_i^2] = \mathrm{Var}[Z_i] = 1 $$
The law of large numbers states that since $(Z_i^2)$ is a sequence of independent random variables with mean $1$, the sequence of the means
$$ \frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{Z_1^2 + \cdots + Z_n^2}{n} = \frac{X_n}{n} $$
converges in almost everywhere towards the mean $1$.